# Delete selected row

Tags: c#, database, dataset

I want to delete a row from my data set,update the content of the listbox and update the content of the database.I have the following piece of code but it seems like nothing happens,all the rows are still there.
What am I not doing?

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter daf = new SqlDataAdapter();
    ds.Tables["Film"].Constraints.Add("PK_Film", ds.Tables["Film"].Columns["id"], true);

    int ind = listBoxchildren.SelectedIndex;
    listBoxchildren.DataSource = null;

    ds.Tables["Film"].Rows[ind].Delete();
        ds.Tables["Film"].AcceptChanges();

    daf.Update(ds,"Film");
    listBoxchildren.DataSource = ds;
    listBoxchildren.DisplayMember = "Director.fk_FilmDir.title";
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbound the data source before deleting the item,

```
int selectedIndex = listBoxchildren.SelectedIndex;
listBoxchildren.DataSource = null;

ds.Tables["Film"].Rows[selectedIndex].Delete();
ds.Tables["Film"].AcceptChanges();
daf.Update(ds,"Film");
listBoxchildren.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: Nope,I'm getting  'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
I think it's because you set the DataSource to null and then SelectedIndex has nothing

Comment: Fixed that by getting the index before assigning null.But the deletion doesn't happen

Comment: @Matt sorry didnt notice that you are accessing the selected index after setting null. will update the answer.